# Why is WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdates Results.WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdates null?

Tags: .net

I am trying to get LastInstallationSuccessDate and LastSearchSuccessDate from the Windows Update API through .Net. I can get IAutomaticUpdates2.Results, but those two properties contained within it are null. Why aren't they date's like the documentation states?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WUApiLib.IAutomaticUpdates2 auc = new WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdates();
        Console.WriteLine(auc.Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate);
        Console.WriteLine(auc.Results.LastSearchSuccessDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working on Windows 7 x64, but not on Windows XP x86.

Comment: I am going to guess that WUApiLib support is limited to Vista and above.

Comment: A simple search on this very website allowed me to discover this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690615/c-sharp-windows-update-api-wuapilib

Comment: Though I'm not convinced its not a supported version problem, the documentation indicates it is available on Windows XP http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826438(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the LastInstallationSuccessDate and LastSearchSuccessDate exist in the COM interface they are **not supported** in Windows XP and always return null.

Likewise the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\InstallLastSuccessTime` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Detect\LastSuccessTime` registry values do not exist in Windows XP.

It appears that parsing %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\ReportingEvents.log could be used to approximate this functionality, but special consideration to performance should be taken since the file can grow to be very large.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the newer API or not, but in the current version of the api you need to call DetectNow() on your auc object. This question is old, but I was having a similar issue with windows 10 - which also returns null Result without the DetectNow() call.

```
        WUApiLib.IAutomaticUpdates2 auc = new WUApiLib.AutomaticUpdates();
        auc.DetectNow(); // get the current values from the system.
        Console.WriteLine(auc.Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate);
        Console.WriteLine(auc.Results.LastSearchSuccessDate);
```